# OAuth bearer token validation by Authorize Attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-mvc-5, bearer-token

I'm stuck with OAuth token authorization. I have configured OAuth and I have my own OAuth server provider.

Configuration code:

```
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/authorize"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
        Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
    };

    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

Server provider:

```
 public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);            
        }
    }
```

When I'm sending: `grand_type=password, username=MyUserName, password=MyPassword` to the OAuth token endpoint `"localhost/token"`, it's nicely creating my OAuth bearer token. But from here, I have no idea how to use this generated token, where it is stored (how to get it), and how to make a success validation using `[Authorize]` attribute on ASP.NET MVC controller. I just simply want to use my generated token, when I'm going from one view to another, that has `[Authorize]` attribute, and pass through it successfully. How can I achive this ?

Comment: you can create a cookie of the refresh token that you generated , this can accessed across multiple views, remember your access token is valid for 1 hour only, you need to generate an new access token every hour

Answer (score 1):

Add new overriden function in "SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider" class.

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
            {
                context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
            }

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
```

Then you can get token in json object.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following workflow :

- Retrieve an access token via password grant-type
- Get user information by passing this access token. Link : http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfo
- Store the claims into the cookie

[image]